# setting a property on a model in an ajax callback

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to set a property on a model in an ajax callback that I can use later, and I'm not sure if I can do this.

```
var self = this;

$.ajax {
   self.views.someProperty = // something i get back from the server

}
```

then later do something with `this.views.someProperty`.  Currently I get this.views.someProperty is undefined.  I was wondering if I'm going about this correctly or not.

Comment: Where is the callback? Does "later" factor in asynchrony?  You should look at more examples and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you code snippet doesn't really make sense.  `$.ajax()` calls a callback function when it's done with the result it retrieved and your code snippet doesn't show that proper form.

Assuming you are properly specifying a callback function, here are some other possible issues:

1. Timing - the result of the ajax call will not be available until AFTER the completion callback is called.  This is some time later after `$.ajax()` is called.  The result will not be available in code that executes right after `$.ajax()`.
2. Does `self.views` exist already?  If not, then setting `self.views.someProperty` would cause an error and would not work.
3. When you access `this.views.someProperty` later, you obviously need to make sure that `this` is the right value.

You can check the first item by putting a `console.log("ajax call finished")` in your ajax completion callback and a `console.log("accessing someProperty")` right before you try to access the value and then verify that the ajax completion is called before you try to access it.

You can check items 2 and 3 by examining the data in the debugger to make sure everything is what you intend.